# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '?'

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, angular7, router-outlet

I am trying to access a sub-route of the sub-route, as you can see in the skills-missions-init-routing.module.ts file, the first route worked but the second one could not access, every time I try to access the route it has this error.

I wonder what would be the way to access the second route without executing this error

**skills-missions-init-routing.module.ts**

```js
const routesSkills: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'skills-missions-init',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id', component: SkillsMissionsInitComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':view', component: ViewMissionComponent, outlet: 'list',
            children: [
              // This is the route I'm trying to access
              { path: 'get-ready-for-mission', component: GetReadyForMissionComponent, outlet: 'list' }, 
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routesSkills)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SkillsMissionsInitRoutingModule { }
```

the model stayed that way

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ViewMissionComponent,
    GetReadyForMissionComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SkillsMissionsInitRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [
    SkillsMissionsInitRoutingModule,
    GetReadyForMissionComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [SkillsMissionsInitComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class SkillsMissionsInitModule { }
```

This route ran executed as desired

The route looks this way.

> http://10.0.3.18:4200/#/skills-missions-init/lead-by-example/(list:11)

```js
  /**
   * redirectViewMission
   */
  public redirectViewMission(id: number, key: string) {
    return this.router.navigate(['/skills-missions-init', key, { outlets: { list: [id] } }], { relativeTo: this.routeActivated });
  }
```

I tried to access the route with this code snippet, but it always displays the error

```js
  /**
   * getReadyForMission
   */
  public getReadyForMission() {
    console.log(this.competency, this.behavior);
    return this.router.navigate(
      [
        'skills-missions-init',
        this.competency,
        { outlets: { list: [this.behavior, 'get-ready-for-mission'] } }
      ],
      { relativeTo: this.routeActivated }
    );
  }
```

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'skills-missions-init/lead-by-example' Error: Cannot
>   match any routes. URL Segment: 'skills-missions-init/lead-by-example'
>       at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError
>   (router.js:2434)
>       at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2415)
>       at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error
>   (catchError.js:34)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error
>   (Subscriber.js:80)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error
>   (Subscriber.js:60)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error
>   (Subscriber.js:80)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error
>   (Subscriber.js:60)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error
>   (Subscriber.js:80)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error
>   (Subscriber.js:60)
>       at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error
>   (tap.js:61)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
>       at zone.js:873
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:14051)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
>       at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask
>   [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
>       at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)

[image]

```js
    ApplyRedirects.prototype.noMatchError = function (e) {
        return new Error("Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '" + e.segmentGroup + "'");
    };
```

[image]

Well I tried to leave the most detailed, if anyone has any more questions and can help me, I'll be waiting.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem quickly, but it's not what I wanted, I used it that way

```js
const routesSkills: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'skills-missions-init',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id', component: SkillsMissionsInitComponent,
        children: [
          { path: ':view', component: ViewMissionComponent, outlet: 'list' },
          { path: ':view/get-ready-for-mission', component: GetReadyForMissionComponent, outlet: 'list' },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routesSkills)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SkillsMissionsInitRoutingModule { }
```

```js
  /**
   * getReadyForMission
   */
  public getReadyForMission() {
    return this.router.navigate(
      [
        'skills-missions-init',
        this.competency,
        { outlets: { list: [this.behavior, 'get-ready-for-mission'] } }
      ],
    );
  }
```

The link stayed that way.

> http://10.0.3.18:4200/#/skills-missions-init/be-digital/(list:14/get-ready-for-mission)